# Android MediaPlayer playback gap when screen is off

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I'm building an Android music player. I have a service holding the MediaPlayer object with a partial wakelock and an onCompletionListener which loads and plays the next song. It's all working as I'd like it to when the screen is on, but when the screen is turned off there is a gap of 10-15 seconds between songs.  Does anyone know what might be causing this incongruity?

Comment: Do you use a foreground service? Maybe you should post some code of the service and how you use it.

Comment: This answer was helüful for me [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42428751/4528239)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had followed Google's guidelines on MediaPlayers. They provide a way to build a PartialWakeLock into the MediaPlayer, and this is a terrible idea since it will lose the WakeLock when changing songs. The solution is to just use a separate WakeLock object. Hope this helps anyone having the same problem!