# Android background service and wake lock

Tags: android, service, background

I have android background service to connect with my RabbitMQ server. My background service listen incoming rabbitmq message. Everything is working well but the problem is appear while screen goes off. My android client disconnect when phone screen goes off. What should I do to always connected with my android rabbitmq client and rabbitmq server ?

My code are below :

```
public class RabbitmqPushService extends Service{

private Thread subscribeThread;
private ConnectionFactory factory;
private Connection connectionSubscribe;
private Channel channelSubscribe;

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

private static final String HOST_NAME = Constant.HOST_NAME; //Rabbitmq Host Name
private static final int PORT_ADDRESS = 5672;

private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "fanout_msg";
private static String QUEUE_NAME = Constant.phone_number+"_queue"; //Queue Name
private static String[] ROUTE_KEY = {"all", Constant.phone_number};


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    setupConnectionFactory();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if(connectionSubscribe != null)
    {
        if(!connectionSubscribe.isOpen())
        {
            connect();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        connect();
    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    if(connectionSubscribe != null)
    {
        disconnectSubscribe();
    }

    NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
}


private void setupConnectionFactory() {
    factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(HOST_NAME);
    factory.setPort(PORT_ADDRESS);
    factory.setUsername(Constant.USERNAME);
    factory.setPassword(Constant.PASSWORD);
    factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(60);
}

private void connect()
{
    final Handler incomingMessageHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String message = msg.getData().getString("msg");
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
                BeepHelper.msgBeep(getApplicationContext());
                sendNotification("From : " + jsonObject.getString("from"), jsonObject.getString("message"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    subscribe(incomingMessageHandler);
    publishToAMQP();
}

private void disconnectSubscribe()
{
    subscribeThread.interrupt();

    try {
        channelSubscribe.close();
        connectionSubscribe.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void subscribe(final Handler handler)
{
    subscribeThread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    connectionSubscribe = factory.newConnection();

                    channelSubscribe = connectionSubscribe.createChannel();

                    channelSubscribe.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "fanout");

                    channelSubscribe.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);


                    for(int i = 0; i<ROUTE_KEY.length; i++)
                    {
                        channelSubscribe.queueBind(QUEUE_NAME, EXCHANGE_NAME, ROUTE_KEY[i]);
                    }

                    QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channelSubscribe);

                    channelSubscribe.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);

                    while (true) {
                        QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();

                        String message = new String(delivery.getBody());

                        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                        bundle.putString("msg", message);
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        handler.sendMessage(msg);

                        channelSubscribe.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);

                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(4000); //sleep and then try again
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    };
    subscribeThread.start();
}


@Override
public void publishMessage(String message) {

    try {
        queue.putLast(message);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void sendNotification(String title, String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: You are starting a Sticky Service. This will make sure that your service will restart if its killed by framework. But if you call stopSelf() then it will get killed and won't start again. In your particular case I am not sure who is killing service. but one option you can try is of aquiring wake lock. If you aquire wakelock then it will prevent framework from killing it. Once your transaction is over then you can release wake lock and let it free for framework to kill it.

Comment: Did this approach worked ??

Answer (score 1):

You need a Wake Lock to keep the phone running when screen is off. Wake locks allow your application to control the power state of the host device.

Add the WAKE_LOCK permission to your application's manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Then add the following in `onCreate()`:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);  
wakelock= pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, getClass().getCanonicalName());
wakelock.acquire();
```

Comment: oncreate on the service? when should I release this wake lock?

Comment: You release it when you're done with the tasks and no longer require the wake lock. You can also do it in the onDestroy of your service.

Answer (score 0):

If your app includes a broadcast receiver that uses a service to do some work, you can manage your wake lock through a WakefulBroadcastReceiver. This is the preferred approach. If your app doesn't follow that pattern, you set a wake lock directly.